# magento connect manager not working in sub-sub-directory

Tags: magento-1.7, admin

After we transfer our magento folder inside another php framework, `example.com/magento`
the magento connect manager is not showing.. it show like it can't find the page.
do i need to configure something to make it work??

This is the error that i got.

```
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
```

**UPDATE 27/07/2015**

ahh add one the the root of your magento folder [github.com/OpenMage/…](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/.htaccess) and change this line  [github.com/OpenMage/…](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/.htaccess#L123) to the sub folder your magento install is located.

Thanks to **rob3000** !!

Comment: can you get to any other pages in your magento site?

Comment: yes, all pages except magento connect manager in the admin panel.

Comment: is there anything in the system or exception logs?

Comment: what do you mean by that? before we transfer magento, everything is okay..

Comment: So when you moved it might not be getting the right base path or could be missing some files. In the log files  `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log`  it might be outputting errors which could help track down the reason why it's not loading.

Comment: i checked the system.log and exception but it doesn't have any error. do i need to configure something in the database??

Comment: Yeah you will need to make sure error logging is turned on in `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings` Enabled is set to 'yes'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26278/discussion-between-user3779015-and-rob3000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be your `.htaccess` has not been set in your magento install. Look at adding the following (https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/.htaccess#L123) and adjusting the rewrite base line to the root of your magento install e.g /public_html/magento